# npm install error in Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a pipeline set up for my Bitbucket repository that runs `npm install` if there is no `node` cache. Up until now it has worked fine, but the `node` cache was recently cleared, and now I'm getting the following output from Bitbucket (Pastebin link, due to character limit): https://pastebin.com/fY9TznNn

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.19",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.55",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.10.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/supercluster": "^5.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.14",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-async": "^10.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-cool-img": "^1.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "supercluster": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.1",
    "use-supercluster": "^0.2.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "npx prettier --write src && npx eslint src --fix --ext .ts --ext .tsx"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.10.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "^1.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
image: node

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &lint
        name: Check code style
        script:
          - npm install # this is where the error occurs
          - npx eslint **/*.ts[x]
        caches:
          - node
    - step: &build
        name: Build and test
        script:
          - echo > ".env"
          - echo REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=$GOOGLE_API_KEY >> ".env"
          - echo REACT_APP_HANDSHAKE_API_KEY=$HANDSHAKE_API_KEY >> ".env"
          - npm install
          - npm run test
          - npm run build
        artifacts:
          - build/**
        caches:
          - node
    - step: &deploy
        name: Deploy to Firebase
        script:
          - cd functions
          - npm install
          - cd ..
          - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:1.0.0
            variables:
              FIREBASE_TOKEN: $FIREBASE_TOKEN
              PROJECT_ID: $FIREBASE_PROJECT

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step: *lint
      - step: *build

  branches:
    master:
      - step: *lint
      - step: *build
      - step: *deploy
```

I'm concerned it might have something to do with the `node-sass` package as I've experienced issues with it before, and it's the first dependency to appear in the error. But I'm really not sure how to interpret this output or how to fix it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my intuition was right—it was because of the `node-sass` package. Apparently it's [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). Installing `sass` instead fixed the problem!